# How to make jQuery UI autocomplete SlideUp working?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

this is my code so far:

```
input.autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
  $.ajax({
    url: searchUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      'action': "opensearch",
      'format': "json",
      'search': request.term
    },
    success: function(data) {
      response(data[1]);
    }
  });
},
open: function(){
    var $ul = $(this).autocomplete("widget");
    $ul.hide().slideDown(500);
    }
});
```

The slideDown works well. I searched https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ but all the events introduced (close, select, change, focus) didn't perform a slideUp. Is there a way to intercept the display none of the ul, that holds the menu, with a slideUp? Thanks for your interest – theo

Answer (score 0):

On the Doc you got : did you tryed?

```
Response( event, ui ) type: autocompleteresponse
```

Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful for local manipulation of suggestion data

You want the ajax part of this UI autocomplete : you try to use $ajax standard from Jquery but this got they own ajax function like this one :

***source***  Multiple types supported:Array, String, Function ...
Here you can call a array to past directly datas, but you **can call the URL using simple string.**

**Array example**

```
input.autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
```

**String example URL called [AJAX]** slideUP at the end

```
input.autocomplete({
  source: searchUrl,
  response: function( event, ui ) { HERE YOU WORK ON DATA }
}).slideUp();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this doesn't perform a slideUp and the doc says:«Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown.» I want to do something when the menu is shown.

Comment: So try _renderItem, _renderMenu or open( event, ui )